# *.php unable to stat

Tags: apache

Very strange errors in my apache log on a new server, obviously I have no *.php file.

```
[Mon Feb 18 08:02:32 2013] [error] [client ::1] script '/var/www/html/*.php' not found or unable to stat
```

Suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Unable to stat just means the file doesn't exist.

Check your code, and make sure there's no place trying to require this *.php. It's somewhat hard to debug without any actual code.

Comment: I assure you I'm not trying to include *.php anywhere.